# What does $u^T$ mean? How to compute this?

Tags: linear-algebra

> if $u = \begin{bmatrix}7\\7\\5\end{bmatrix}$
>
> then $uu^T = \begin{bmatrix}\\\\\\\end{bmatrix}$ and $u^Tu = \begin{bmatrix}\\\\\end{bmatrix}$

What in the world does the $T$ mean? Also, are they asking me to compute $u \times$ the "transpose" of the $u$ matrix? Or what exactly are they asking me here? Also why are they asking me to compute the same thing but that consists of a 1x1 matrix to the right of it just rearranged? I'm really confused

Comment: The transpose of $u$ (a 3$\times$ 1 matrix) is a 1 $\times$ 3 matrix-read more about it-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $T$ means transpose:
$$u^T=\left[\begin{matrix}7 & 7 & 5\end{matrix}\right]$$
They're asking you to compute both $uu^T$ and $u^Tu$ because they give you very different results, which you'll see if you multiply these two matrices out.

Hint: $uu^T$ is a 3-by-3 matrix and $u^Tu$ is a 1-by-1 matrix.

Comment: So the takeaway from this problem is that multiplication of matrices with their transpose version is **NOT** commutative lol

Comment: @Shammy Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

$u^T$ means the transpose of $u$. So in this case, $u^T = [\begin{array}{ccc} 7 & 7 & 5\end{array}]$. The expressions $u^T u$ and $u u^T$ refer to the product of $u$ and $u^T$ using matrix multiplication.